Time Travel. Young Girl meets her older self - Who doesn't like her
Looking for novel I read in or around the 1980s - May have been novelisation of tv series from somewhat earlier.
Some children travel into the future, and one of them meets her grown-up self - who is distinctly hostile to her, observing that "I was an idiot when I was you.".
I think the adult version called herself Beth, though that wasn't her original name. She may have been working at a research station of some kind.

Clones from the Future (2016) has a time-traveling character named Beth who repeatedly states that her earlier self was stupid "when I was you". She says it several times; https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Clones_from_the_Future/RArgDQAAQBAJ?hl=en

Yes. I'm pretty sure Timeslip is the one. Cheers.

This is the TV series Timeslip (1970), specifically The Time of the Ice Box.

Traynor persuades the children to return to the Ice Box and Liz is stunned when she encounters first her mother, and then her future self – a cold, emotionless, scientist going by the name Beth (Mary Preston) – working in the Ice Box.

The episode features this line:

Beth: My dear, I was a little idiot when I was you. I had to do something about forcing myself to grow up, finding a purpose to my existence. We can’t be fools all our lives, I’m afraid.

A novelisation of the episode was written by James Boswell.

Now listen to me, Liz,’ she said in a more even tone. ‘People change. At a certain time in my life. I had to take some important decisions. Break with the past and become a different kind of person.’
‘But why?’ Liz wanted to know.
‘Because I was a little idiot when I was you.’ She was obviously finding it an effort to keep the passion out of her voice. ‘I had to do something about forcing myself to grow up. I needed to find a purpose to my existence. We can’t stay fools all our lives.’

